# registerForRemoteNotifications works on iOS9, fails on iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios9

For the user to allow badge / sound / alert and to get the notification token, I use the simple and classic code (for iOS >= 8) in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

After calling this code on an iOS9 device, the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` callback is called and I get my token.

But running the exact same code, same bundleId, on an iOS8 device gives me an error (through the `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` callback).

The error is the "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application", which doesn't make sense in this case because it's working fine on iOS9!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was happening only while deploying apps on devices through Xcode, it worked as expected when deployed OTA with an enterprise certificate :/